# Odd behaviour with 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: keyboard, firefox

My system has just upgraded to 22.04.1 LTS and I have an irritating problems, can anybody shed any light on it.

I’m getting the following messages repeatedly in Firefox (with the number of days counting down):

> Pending update of Firefox Snap. Close the app to avoid any
> disruptions. Pending update of “Snap Store” Snap. Close the app to
> avoid any disruptions. XX days left.

I have closed and opened FF, and restarted the machine – no change.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please one question at a time. For the first issue close FF and run `sudo snap refresh`. The question in this format will be closed soon.